Is it possible to partition the SRAM on a Raspberry Pi pico?
I have a MicroPython application for the Raspberry Pi pico where I want to split the SRAM between the two cores, i.e. core 1 cannot access the SRAM assigned to core 2.
Is this possible?

No.  In an embedded environment like that, where you don't have users from the outside, you're expected to handle that yourself in the code.
